# Clonezilla vs. FOG on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, uefi, clone, clonezilla, fog

I am hopeful that someone in this community will be able to help me. I am stumbling my way through my first experience with any form of Linux computing. Since 2003 I have used Windows and Symantec's Ghost software to image laptops at my place of work. This year we got new computers with the new UEFI BIOS, and we changed over to Windows 8.1.  Ghost, no longer being supported, does not work in Windows 8.

I decided it was time to get an updated mass imaging solution, one that people are actually using and updating.

I tried Clonezilla live on a flash drive, created the image, and pushed it back to a different machine with no problem whatsoever. The next step was to get something that can do mass imaging, since we need to do 900 of these laptops. I installed Ubuntu with FOG and created the image and pushed it back, only to have it not be bootable.
I get a recovery error is [in???] Windows which I think means it has something to do with the image process not properly handling the boot partition.

The questions is why if both Clonezilla and FOG use PARTCLONE 0.2.69 does one work and one does not?  Is there anyone out there who knows the details behind the scenes on how this software works? With my limited experience I don't even know how to troubleshoot what's different.

Comment: In my experience it is very hard to get any help or support for CloneZilla. They had an ambition to make it easy, but it really isn't simple, there are always problems. And when asking for help either here, SuperUser or at their SourceForge forum, I don't get any. I wish I had paid for a commercial solution, even though I am pro open source and prefer Linux over Windows.